# NP Completeness of 3-SAT problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, satisfiability, 3-sat

I have started reading on algorithmic complexity for my thesis work. Already have studied on Polynomial time reducibility, NP-Complete, NP-Hard. Now trying to prove NP completeness of some of the classical problems. I have started with 3-SAT problem.

3-SAT problem — was shown to be NP-complete:

> Input: A boolean Formula F in CNF where each clause contains at most three variables.
>
> Question: Is that formula satisfiable?

Show now that the simple 3-SAT problem is also NP-complete:

> Input: A boolean Formula F in CNF where each clause contains at most three variables and only clauses of length two may contain negated variables.
>
> Question: Is that formula satisfiable?

Can any please explain the main idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For general ideas and approaches, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/472) and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/472).

Comment: this is one of the most common/basic/earliest NP complete reductions found in many refs.... eg [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability). also there is some connection to the [tseitin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main idea: For each variable $x_i$ introduce a new variable $y_i$ and add a new clause $(\lnot x_i, \lnot y_i)$. Replace each occurence of $\lnot x_i$ in the original clauses by $y_i$.

The new clauses ensure that $y_i$ can be set to true if and only if $x_i$ is false. Thus we neither add nor remove satisfying assignments for the original clauses, while the new clauses can always be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you. Seems I have got some idea. Is there any way to reduce to graph problem?

Comment: Any NP-complete problem can be reduced to any other NP-complete problem. The question is just how complex the reduction function will get.