# When proving a problem is NP-C, how do I select another NP-C problem for the transformation?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, proof-techniques

I'm taking an algorithms course in which we are discussing proofs that problems are NP-Complete.

Our proofs usually take the form:

Given a problem $\Pi$,
 1. Prove that $\Pi$ is NP.
 2. Select an NP-C problem $\Pi'$.
 3. Find a transformation $\propto$ from $\Pi'$ to $\Pi$.
 4. Prove that $\propto$ is polynomial.
 5. Prove that iff a solution $S$ to $\Pi'$ is correct, then $\propto(S)$ is a solution to $\Pi$.

I have a question about step $2$. When I'm attempting to prove that a problem $\Pi$ is NP-C, how do I go about selecting $\Pi'$? Is there a systematic approach I can use? If not, what is the intuition behind selecting $\Pi'$, and how can I practice and develop that intuition?

Comment: The dumb answer is, *any* $\Pi' \in \mathsf{NPC}$ works. So you are probably asking, is there a strategy for picking "good" reduction partners? None that I know of. This might be a duplicate of [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other). Oh wait, I found a better one.

Comment: You a quite right. The [Finding Reductions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/finding-reductions) question was exactly what I was asking for. Should I delete this duplicate?

Comment: (Also, thank you for finding answer for me!)

Comment: You are welcome, that's what we're here for. :) We tend to leave duplicates around (if they are not verbatim copies) in the hope that more searches are sucessful.