# How to prove QUADPROG is NP-hard using 3COLOR?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, np-hard, quadratic-programming

I am given a task to prove using 3COLOR that Quadratic Programming is NP-hard. Does anyone have a clue on how this is meant to be done?

Comment: You're probably meant to try applying techniques you've seen in your course or textbook, and use this so you can practice those techniques -- not copy-paste the exercise into a website and wait for someone else to tell you how to solve it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: You might be interested in our reference questions on reductions: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755.