# Check if K-Sum Variation is NP-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, subset-sum

## Problem

Given a range of integers $\{a,a+1,...,b-1,b\}$, find a subset of size $k$ such that the sum is equal to $s$.

## Question

This problem came from evaluating some scheduling algorithms that I am interested in optimizing for some small home grown useless embedded system I am playing with. My problem is that I do not know if this problem is **NP-Complete** like the **K-Sum** problem. I am guessing it might be but it has been a while since I have dealt with proofs pertaining to **NP** problems. I remember something with **SAT**, but looking around did not jog any memories (at least any good ones).

How might I prove it is or is not **NP-Complete**?

Comment: Are you aware [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is NP-complete?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes, I am aware of this. And __k-sum__ is essentially the subset sum problem, correct?

Comment: Is that sufficient enough to prove that this problem is __NP-Complete__? I thought it involved more gymnastics than that?

Comment: So, essentially all I have to say is that the range of numbers is my set for the __k-sum__ problem and it is now __NP-Complete__?

Comment: Wait. I might not be careful enough. "Given a range of numbers $[a,\cdots,b]$", do you mean a list of number $a_1, a_2, \cdots, c_n$? When we compute the time-complexity, is it in terms of $n$ or in terms of $k$ and $n$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack A range of numbers where the minimum of the range is $a$ and the maximum of the range is $b$. So my set includes $a$, $a+1$, ..., $b-1$, $b$. I see where the confusion might be happening. I edited my question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question!

> Given a range of integers $\{a,a+1,...,b−1,b\}$, find a subset of size $k$ such that the sum is equal to $s$.

Well, this problem can be solved in $O(n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of given integers.

(**Continuity of $k$-sums**). Given integers $\{a,a+1,...,a+n-1\}$, an integer $k$, $1\le k\le n$ and an integer $s$, there are $k$ integers whose sum is $s$ if and only if $ka+\dfrac{(k-1)k}2\le s\le k(a+n-1)-\dfrac{(k-1)k}2$

Here is the algorithm.

---

Check if $ka+\dfrac{(k-1)k}2\le s\le k(a+n-1)-\dfrac{(k-1)k}2$. If not, return none.

Let $sum = s$. Let $S$ be an empty set.
For $i$ from 0 to $n-1$ do the following.

- Let $temp = sum -(b - i)$.
- If  $temp\le (k-i-1)(a+n-1)-\dfrac{(k-i-2)(k-i-1)}2$,
  let $sum = temp$ and insert $b-i$ into $S$. Otherwise, do nothing.
- If $sum = 0$, break the loop.

Return S.

---

Here are a few related exercises.

**Exercise 1.** Prove the proposition of continuity of $k$-sums.

**Exercise 2.** Show the algorithm is correct.

**Exercise 3.** Modify the algorithm so that it will try adding the smallest number first.

**Exercise 3.** Modify the algorithm so that it will run in $O(k)$ time.

Comment: Thank you for the exercises.This makes a lot more sense now:)

Comment: Depending on how you interpret "find a subset of sum k", you can do this in constant time. Not if you insist on k numbers, but if you allow something like "the numbers from 12 to 17, plus the numbers from 19 to 24" or "the numbers from 12 to 24 except 18" as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a polynomial-time algorithm exists.  WLOG, you can assume $a=0$ (subtract $a$ from all numbers in the range, and subtract $ak$ from $s$).  Then the problem becomes: given a range $\{0,\dots,b\}$, find a subset of size $k$ that sums to $s$.  If you allow a multiset, it is easy to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm; take $k-1$ copies of $\lfloor s/(k-1) \rfloor$ and one copy of $s - \lfloor s/(k-1) \rfloor$.  I suspect similar ideas can probably be applied to find a set as well (i.e., to avoid repeats).  I suggest you spend some time working out the details to see.