# How can I reduce Subset Sum to Almost Subset Sum?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Maybe this is quite simple, but I am having some trouble how to do this reduction. I want to reduce Subset Sum to Almost Subset Sum.

Subset Sum: given a set of positive integers $A=\{a_1,a_2, \dots,a_n\}$ and an integer $M$, decide if there is a subset of $A$ with a sum equal to $M$.

Almost Subset Sum:

Input: a set of positive integers $A=\{a_1,a_2, \dots,a_n\}$, and a positive integer $M$.

Goal: decide whether there is a subset of $A$ with sum $S$ such that $|M −S| < d$ where $d = ⌊\log M ⌋$?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Try multiplying everything ($A$ and $M$) by a large enough number.

Comment: Thank you both for your input! I tried many different approaches (adding, logging, dividing, and even multiplication). I thought I had forgot about a trivial logarithmic rule. I read a bit and tried your approach Yuval. Multiplying A and M by 10 seems to have done it!