# How to prove NP-hardness from scratch?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard

I am working on a problem of whose complexity is unknown.
By the nature of the problem, I cannot use long edges as I please, so 3SAT and variants are almost impossible to use.

Finally, I have decided to go for the most primitive method -- Turing Machines.

Oddly enough, I could not find any example of NP-hardness reduction done directly by modeling the problem as a language, and showing that a deterministic Turing Machine cannot decide whether a given instance belongs to that language (I might've messed up with the terminology here).

So, assuming that there are no problems to perform an NP-hardness reduction, how does one prove that a problem is NP-hard? Are there any publications that does this?

I also want to add that I know how to perform an NP-hardness reduction. However, the problem that I am tackling is a "localized" geometric problem, that it does not allow me to model any given instance of 3SAT, 3-coloring, vertex cover, etc.

The immediate question comes to mind: "what if the problem is polynomial time solvable?"
Well, that is also a possibility, but I want to exhaust everything before I move onto designing an algorithm.

Comment: What about the proof of the [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only two methods I've seen are (a) a reduction or (b) direct proof (as in the proof of the [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem)).  It is almost universally the case that a reduction is easier than a direct proof.  Therefore, I suggest you keep trying to find a reduction, and consider other reduction partners.  There are lots and lots of problems known to be NP-complete; perhaps you can find one that is a more suitable partner than 3SAT.

Possibly useful: [How do I construct reductions between problems to prove a problem is NP-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755).

Answer (score 3):

> Oddly enough, I could not find any example of NP-hardness reduction done directly by modeling the problem as a language, and showing that a deterministic Turing Machine cannot decide whether a given instance belongs to that language (I might've messed up with the terminology here)

That's not odd at all: it's because no such proof exists. Anything that can be computed can be computed by a deterministic Turing machine. Any proof that no *polynomial-time* deterministic Turing machine can decide some problem in $\text{NP}$ would constitute a proof that $\mathrm{P}\neq\mathrm{NP}$, resolving the biggest open problem in computer science. There are proofs that polynomial-time deterministic Turing machines can't decide certain classes of $\text{NP}$-hard languages: see the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem). However, if $\mathrm{P}\neq\mathrm{NP}$ then, it is a consequence of [Ladner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) that there are problems that cannot be solved by polynomial-time deterministic Turing machines but which are not $\text{NP}$-hard.

To me, the fact that you considered this as an approach, and that you think there are no problems to reduce from (as distinct from no *convenient* problems), suggests that you don't fully understand what $\text{NP}$-hardness is.  I suggest you check out [our reference question on the subject](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/9550).