# In which paper is written that you can transform one problem to another to show NP-completeness?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

For example in this post they discuss how to construct a reduction between problems to show that one probleme is NP-Hard:
[Post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/how-do-i-construct-reductions-between-problems-to-prove-a-problem-is-np-complete)

I am searching for a scientific paper to cite where it is written, that this is a valid method.

Does anybody knows one?

Comment: [Polynomial-time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) on Wikipedia has a lot of references that could be helpful. Indeed, this is standard textbook material.

Comment: Try Karp’s classic paper On the reducibility of combinatorial problems. You can also cite relevant textbooks.

Comment: Another relevant result is Cook-Levin teorem (Cook's paper should include some useful citations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may make an assumption, you want such a reference to be able to put it in one of your works, right ? I don't why you would wanna do that as if you have a problem A, reducting a NP Hard problem to problem A quite clearly shows that A is NP Hard. No one bothers proving it as it's such a straightforward and fundamental result. If you need to prove it for some reason you can do it in two lines. If you still want a reference for a reader to read about NP in general then just quote Arora and Barak's book on complexity theory.