# Reduction techniques in complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

I am learning computational complexity and parameter complexity. In order to proof that a problem is np-hard, we should reduction one which is np-hard to the problem. However, I don't have any idea about the various reductions of problem.
How should I learn the reduction  technique, is there a special teaching material or information?
Greatful!

Comment: usually it boils down to understanding the definitions of the problems well enough and choosing the appropriate NP-hard problem to reduce from

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755

Comment: Thank you! It is so hard.