# Showing NP-Completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

I just newly started looking into computational complexity.

Since we don’t know if P = NP, we would like to have a way of saying “This problem is in NP and is really hard unless P = NP.”

This is made more formal by the notion of NP-completeness.

Therefore, we say a problem A is NP-complete if

(a) it is in NP, and (b) every problem B in NP is polynomial-time reducible to A.

Using a graph $G$ and an edge $e$ in $G$ as an example, how do I determine whether or not there is a Hamiltonian cycle that includes $e$?

With this, I could show that the problem is NP-complete and use the same approach for similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known efficient way to determine whether or not there is a Hamiltonian cycle that includes $e$.  That is a NP-complete problem.  (If you could determine that, you could use that as a subroutine to test whether the graph contains any Hamiltonian cycle, and even to find a Hamiltonian cycle if one exists; so it's not reasonable to expect there to be an efficient algorithm to do that.)

Comment: @ D.W. True...How do I then simply prove that the problem I used as an example is an NP-complete problem?

Comment: @Mike, via a reduction - see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1240/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755

Comment: Many thanks! I would look through

Answer (score 0):

A problem is in NP if every instance with the answer “yes” can be solved in polynomial time if you get a clever hint.

A problem X is NP complete if it is in NP (and not harder), and some NP-complete problem can be solved by solving X. That means if I take an instance Y of this other NP-complete problem then I can construct a problem X so a solution of X allows me to solve Y. That doesn’t require that X is easy to solve.